# Python pandas recursive function polynomial form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function using Pandas dataframe in python.

I read through, and there seems to be a few different methods, either for/if loop or Dataframe.apply methods; or scipy.signal.lfilter. However, `lfilter` doesn't work for me as my recursive formula can be of a polynomial form.

The recursive formula I am looking to do is :

> x(t) = A * Bid + B * x(t-1)^C + BidQ

I looked through some examples, and one possibility is of the form below.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from scipy.signal import lfilter

@xw.func
@xw.ret(expand='table')
def py_Recursive(v, lamda_, AscendType):
    df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['Bid', 'Ask', 'BidQ', 'AskQ'])
    df = df.sort_index(ascending=AscendType)
    NewBid = lfilter([1], [1,-2], df['Bid'].astype=(float))
    df = df.join(NewBid)
    df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
    return df
```

`lamda_` is a decay function that potentially will be used in the future and `AscendType` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

My input data-set for `v` is as per below

```
v =
763.1  763.3    89    65
762.5  762.7   861   687
772.1  772.3   226   761
770.6  770.8   927   333
777.8  778.0    59   162
786.5  786.7   125   431
784.7  784.9   915   595
776.8  777.0   393   843
777.7  777.9   711   935
771.6  771.8   871   956
770.0  770.2   727   300
768.7  768.9   565   923
```

Comment: the parameter `lamda_` is never used in your function, what is the purpose?

Comment: lambda_ is a decay function that potentially will be used in the future. It is not in the formula now, but it would then take the form of = A * Bid + exp(-lambda) * x(t-1)^C + BidQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I was not able to run your code, but I think what you can do to create your column recursively and with the formula you gave:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['Bid', 'Ask', 'BidQ', 'AskQ'])
# initialise your parameters, but they can be a function of something else
A, B, C = 10, 2, 0.5
x0 = 1
#create the column x filled with x0 first
df['x'] = x0
# now change each row depending on the previous one and other information
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df.loc[i,'x'] = A*df.loc[i,'Bid'] + B*df.loc[i-1,'x']**C + df.loc[i,'BidQ']
```

Comment: thanks Ben,it works! Small syntax where df['x'] = x0 (not xo)

Answer (score 0):

I was tinkering around with various ways, and below is a more complete code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from scipy.signal import lfilter

# if using xlwings addin
@xw.func
@xw.ret(expand='table')
df = pd.DataFrame(v, A=10, B=2, C=0.5, columns=['Bid', 'Ask', 'BidQ', 'AskQ'])
# initialise your parameters, but they can be a function of something else
Trend = pd.Series(1, name = 'Trend')
df = df.join(Trend)
#create the column Trend filled with 1 first
# now change each row depending on the previous one and other information
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df.loc[i,'Trend'] = A * df.loc[i,'Bid'] + B * df.loc[i-1,'Trend']**C + df.loc[i,'BidQ']
return df
```